# How to allow Outlook Add-In read the config file

Tags: wix, outlook-addin, advanced-installer

We are developing an Outlook Add-In VSTO using C#, it reads a configuration by using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"].

We made a .msi installer by WIX and installed to Outlook, then the Add-In can't read the config value.

But when trying with Advanced Installer, the add-in works perfectly.

I'm not sure what the Advanced Installer does with my msi file (or registry), can you please help me to solve the problem with WIX because we want a free installer creator tool (Advanced Installer costs me 1500$).

Thanks a lot

Comment: Advanced Installer can package Office add-ins within the Professional edition, which costs only 399$, you don't need the Enterprise edition (unless you also need other more complex features). Also you should take into account the additional time your spending on building a solution with a free tool, your time costs too...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Advanced Installer is useful, especially it doesn't require user to have programming skills. However, if we need to customize UI then we need to buy the Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 0):

Does the add-in assembly name correspond to the config file name? Are they located in the same folder? Is the config file deployed?

The [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx#AddD) article provides all the required steps for creating Windows installer setup programs.